# Sql Server: A seemingly strange behaviour of BEGIN TRAN - COMMIT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

First create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (Id INT)
CREATE TABLE abc (Id INT)
```

Please, observe the following SQL code:

```
DELETE FROM abc
BEGIN TRAN
EXEC('
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (1),(2)
DECLARE @x INT = (SELECT Id FROM xyz)
')
INSERT INTO abc VALUES (1)
COMMIT

SELECT * FROM abc
```

Running it outputs the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

**And there is no result**. All as expected.

Now let us change the error to a syntax error by replacing `xyz)` with `xyz`. Here is the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'xyz'.
```

But this time there is a result:

[image]

Why? What is going on?

Comment: Can you explain why you've re-introduced [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40349938/61305)?

Comment: I am not sure what is the right forum - SO or DBA. Judging by the number of views posting it on SO was probably a mistake in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the behaviour of your first example by specifying:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
```

At the top of your script, then you don't get a result. You do get a result as you describe if you specify `SET XACT_ABORT OFF`.

The reason for the different behaviour is the second example "replacing `xyz)` with `xyz`" contains a syntax error i.e. the EXEC batch is parsed, syntax error discovered and the batch is not run. The EXEC is a separate batch (this is the reason you cannot define variables outside of EXEC and reference them inside) and processing continues with the rest of the transaction.

For the first example "`(SELECT Id FROM xyz)`", this is valid syntax, so the batch parses correctly. The error is only found at run time and processing continues if `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` but stops if `SET XACT_ABORT ON`.

Comment: Is there a way to handle **all** the errors the same without resorting to BEGIN TRY-END CATCH, using which results in a more verbose code - one has to rollback manually (Internet says I need to check `@@TRANCOUNT` before doing it) and rethrow the original error using `THROW`. Much code.

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour depends on [SET XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx) and is explained in the following quote from the linked article.

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
> run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
> statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
> continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the
> entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.
> OFF is the default setting.